# LINQ to XML - amend

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

This has been driving me mad all day. I have an xdocument and simply want to change a value.

xml looks as follows

```
<session>
  <immediate>
<pivot name="test">
  <axes>
    <axis position="SLICERS">
      <attribute name="Book">
        <selection value="Book_Name" type="Book" />
      </attribute>
      <attribute name="Result Namespace">
        <selection value="blah blah" />
      </attribute>
      <attribute name="Date">
        <selection value="2012-05-16" />
      </attribute>
      <attribute name="Measure">
        <selection value="123" />
      </attribute>
    </axis>
    <axis position="SIDE">
      <attribute name="ttx" mode="ALL"></attribute>
    </axis>
    <axis position="TOP">
      <attribute name="hhy" mode="ALL"></attribute>
    </axis>
  </axes>
  <source name="risk" />
  <aggregate expression="SUM(Money Value)" />
  <grid-processor name="errors" />
</pivot>
  </immediate>
</session>
```

What I want to do is simply change the

```
<attribute name="Book">
        <selection value="Book_Name" type="Book" />
</attribute>
```

to

```
<attribute name="Book">
    <selection value="CorrectBookName" type="Book" />
</attribute>
```

I would like to use LINQ and have tried the XElement - I can get the block but cant update

```
        XElement amend = xdoc.Descendants("attribute").First(el => (String)el.Attribute("selection") == "value");
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the XElement.SetAttributeValue() method. Just select the element whose attribute you want to change and call SetAttributeValue() on it. If there is not attribute with the name you provide a new attribute will be created otherwise the value of the existing attribute will be replaced with the new one. Take a look at msdn for more an example and more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue.aspx

Comment: I have been trying that. 
amend.SetAttributeValue("value", "CorrectBookName");
results in 
<attribute name="Book" value="CorrectBookName">
  <selection value="BOOK_NAME" type="Book Hierarchy" />
</attribute>

Comment: Ignore that - needed to select the next level

            XElement amend = xdoc.Descendants("selection").First(el => (String)el.Attribute("type").Value=="Book Hierarchy");